# How do you access pySDL2 SoftwareSpriteRenderSystem Blendmode?

Tags: python, sdl-2, renderer, pysdl2

The problem is very simple. I want to change the **Blendmode** for my SDL2 Renderer in Python, but I don't know how to access the Renderer.

The [PySDL2 Documentation here](http://pysdl2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/sdl2ext_sprite.html#sdl2.ext.Renderer) states that you can define colors with an Alpha channel:

> **class sdl2.ext.Renderer**
>
> **blendmode:** The blend mode used for drawing
> operations (fill and line). This can be a value of
>
> . SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE for no blending
>
> . SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND for alpha blending
>
> . SDL_BLENDMODE_ADD for additive color blending
>
> . SDL_BLENDMODE_MOD for multiplied color blending

All I need is to set the Blendmode to **SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND** so that I can use the Alpha channels. My problem is that I'm using a  **SoftwareSpriteRenderSystem**

```
self.Renderer = self.SpriteFactory.create_sprite_render_system(self.Window)
```

There isn't any clear way to change the blendmode here. I can **try** doing the following:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(self.Renderer,SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND)
```

But this returns:

**`ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_SDL_Renderer instance instead of SoftwareSpriteRenderSystem`**

Could anyone help me out please? I'd just like to be able to get some transparent Sprites (from_rect sprites), but it's proving difficult because the SDL_renderer is inaccessible.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you want to have sprites that contain an alpha channel or do you want to blend on basic draw and fill operations?

Comment: @Marcus I want to have sprites that contain an alpha channel. I use 'from_color' to create my basic shapes (not from_rect my bad), so however you set transparency for sprites would be what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need or want sprites with solid colors, that contain an alpha channel, blending will only be relevant, if you actually render things on you screen and is not relevant, when you are creating textures.

The blend flags from your initial question are only supported, if you do not use software-based rendering. This means that you must not used a `SpriteFactory` that provides a `SoftwareSpriteRenderSystem`, but a `SpriteFactory` with a `TEXTURE` sprite type.

A brief example to create a texture-based renderer and factory for a window:

```
window = sdl2.ext.Window("Test", size=(800,600))
renderer = sdl2.ext.Renderer(window)
#     use renderer.blendmode = ... to change the blend mode
factory = sdl2.ext.SpriteFactory(sdl2.ext.TEXTURE, renderer=renderer)
rsystem = factory.create_sprite_render_system(window)
```

Note that you will receive `TextureSprite` objects from the `SpriteFactory`, which do *not* allow
you to access pixels in the same way as `SoftwareSprite` or `SDL_Surface` objects would do.

To create a `TextureSprite` with an alpha channel, make sure that you use 32 bpp and an alpha mask in your `factory.from_color()` call.

```
# Create a solid, quadratic, red texture of 100px in size, using a RGBA color layout.
factory.from_color(0xFF000000, size=(100, 100),
                   masks=(0xFF000000,           # red channel
                          0x00FF0000,           # green channel
                          0x0000FF00,           # blue channel
                          0x000000FF))          # alpha channel
```

Comment: So I need to use TextureSprites to create transparency? I've only got softwaresprites in my GUI. How do I render both if I'm using a SoftwareSpriteRenderSystem to render my sprites?

Comment: No, you only need them, if you want to use the builtin blending features of the SDL renderer. You can get alpha transparency for  software sprites using the `from_color()` call above, too.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was not previously using masks. That is the solution. Now I can modify the alpha channel in order to get a result. Awesome. It appears that you cannot, however, make the window itself transparent. There will always be a black box representing the window size. An understandable limitation.